# Gradient approximation on non-uniform quadrilateral mesh

Tags: numerical-methods, vector-analysis, approximation

I have non-uniform quadrilateral mesh. For each volume from my mesh I have a point which represents the volume. I need gradient approximation using representation points.

Any ideas?